# Why can't i import NMS in Spigot?

Tags: java, spigot

```
import net.minecraft.server;
```

gives me the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'minecraft'
```

How do i fix this? The version of spigot api i am using is

```
spigot-api-1.14.4-R0.1-20191205.000449-89-shaded.jar
```

When i tried to `import net.minecraft.server`, it couldnt find it. Do i have a dependency issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spigot does not include NMS with its maven packages.
The legal way to do what you are after is to download [BuildTools](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/) and run it via:

```
java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.14.4
```

This command will not only build Spigot but also install the resulting artifacts to your local maven repository. Then, you can include your dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spigot-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.4-R0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that you have to change `spigot-api` to `spigot-server` which is the artifact that also includes NMS.